# Геокодер не находит координаты организации

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, геокодинг

Поисковый запрос одинаковый для всех примеров ниже - `Тамбов ТРЦ Рио`.

1. Запрос к Геокодеру возвращает Бразилию:

   [https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x//?format=json&geocode=Тамбов%20ТРЦ%20Рио&apikey=](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x//?format=json&geocode=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%A6%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BE&apikey=)...
2. Запрос такого же адреса к JavaScript API возвращает так же Бразилию:

   [https://enterprise.api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_...&text=Тамбов%20ТРЦ%20Рио&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=20&token=...&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&type=geo&apikey=](https://enterprise.api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_...&text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%A6%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BE&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=20&token=...&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&type=geo&apikey=)...
3. Но если из запроса к JavaScript API убрать `&type=geo`, то он возвращает торговый центр в Тамбове, как и ожидается:

   [https://enterprise.api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_...&text=Тамбов%20ТРЦ%20Рио&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=20&token=...&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&apikey=](https://enterprise.api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_...&text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%A6%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BE&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=20&token=...&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&apikey=)...

Вопрос в том, как правильно использовать Геокодер, чтобы он возвращал торговый центр в Тамбове, как в третьем примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геокодер - это API для конвертации *адресов* в координаты и наоборот. Он не умеет искать организации и, в общем случае, вообще не предназначен для поиска.

В JS API вы приводите запрос не к геокодеру, а к внутреннему сервису, который обеспечивает общение JS API и бэкенда Яндекса. Параметр `type=geo` в этом запросе, очевидно, означает, что запрос сделан к Геокодеру, а без него это просто поиск чего-угодно на карте по вашему запросу.

**Что делать**

- Если нужен JS API, то использовать поиск по организациям; для этого нужно в контроле поиска задать провайдер `yandex#search`, как [в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo?from=SO).
- Если нужен HTTP API, то использовать специальный [HTTP API Геопоиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=SO) - он умеет искать и организации, и адреса.